# Drawing lines in GUI with arrow keys using keylistener in Java

Tags: java, keylistener

I am working on a keylistener exercise for my java class, but have been stuck for the past week.  I appreciate any helpful suggestions.  The exercise is:

"Write a program that draws line segments using the arrow keys. The 
line starts from the center of the frame and draws toward east, north, 
west, or south when the right-arrow key, up-arrow key, left-arrow key, 
or down-arrow key is clicked."

Through debugging I figured out that the KeyListener works to the point 
of getting to drawComponent(Graphics g), but it only draws when I press 
down or right and that only works the first couple times.  Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class EventProgrammingExercise8 extends JFrame {

    JPanel contentPane;
    LinePanel lines;
    public static final int SIZE_OF_FRAME = 500;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    EventProgrammingExercise8 frame = new EventProgrammingExercise8();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public EventProgrammingExercise8() {
        setTitle("EventExercise8");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(SIZE_OF_FRAME, SIZE_OF_FRAME);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        lines = new LinePanel();
        contentPane.add(lines);
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setOpaque(true);
        lines.setOpaque(true);

        lines.setFocusable(true);
        lines.addKeyListener(new ArrowListener());
    }

    private class LinePanel extends JPanel {

        private int x;
        private int y;
        private int x2;
        private int y2;

        public LinePanel() {
            x = getWidth() / 2;
            y = getHeight() / 2;
            x2 = x;
            y2 = y;
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.drawLine(x, y, x2, y2);
            x = x2;
            y = y2;
        }

        public void drawEast() {
            x2 += 5;
            repaint();
        }

        public void drawWest() {
            x2 -= 5;
            repaint();
        }

        public void drawNorth() {
            y2 -= 5;
            repaint();
        }

        public void drawSouth() {
            y2 += 5;
            repaint();
        }

    }

    private class ArrowListener extends KeyAdapter {

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int key = e.getKeyCode();
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                lines.drawEast();
            } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                lines.drawWest();
            } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                lines.drawNorth();
            } else {
                lines.drawSouth();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Personally, I'd use the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), it's a safer bet in the long run, but you may have reasons not to do this...

Comment: Thanks.  I've heard of key bindings, but haven't seen them used.  Generally we're only supposed to use techniques we've seen in class.  I'll look further into key bindings though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things jump out at me...

```
public LinePanel() {
    x = getWidth() / 2;
    y = getHeight() / 2;
```

This will be an issue, because at the time you construct the class, it's size is `0x0`

Apart from the fact that you haven't called `super.paintComponent` which breaks the paint chain, you seem to think that painting is accumaltive...

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawLine(x, y, x2, y2);
    x = x2;
    y = y2;
}
```

Painting in Swing is destructive.  That is, you are expected to erase to the `Graphics` context and rebuild the output from scratch.  The job `paintComponent` is to clear the `Graphics` context ready for painting, but you've not called `super.paintComponent`, breaking the paint chain and opening yourself up to a number of very ugly paint artifacts

Calling `setSize(SIZE_OF_FRAME, SIZE_OF_FRAME);` on a frame is dangerous, as it makes no guarantee about the frames border insets, which will reduce the viewable area available to you.

This....

```
contentPane = new JPanel(); 
lines = new LinePanel();
contentPane.add(lines);
setContentPane(contentPane);
```

Is not required, it just adds clutter to your code.  It's also a good hint as to what is going wrong with your code.

`JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout` by default.  A `FlowLayout` uses the component's preferred size to determine how best to layout the components.  The default preferred size of a component is `0x0`

You could use...

```
lines = new LinePanel();
add(lines);
```

instead or set the `contentPane` to use a `BorderLayout` which will help...

Try adding `lines.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));` add see what you get...

Oddly, during my testing, your `KeyListener` worked fine...

Basically...

- Override the `getPreferredSize` method of the `LinePanel` and return the size of the panel you would like to use.
- Use a `java.util.List` to maintain a list of `Point`s that need to be painted.
- In you `paintComponent` method, use the `Point` `List` to actually render you lines.  This will be a bit tricky, as you need two points and the `List` may contain an odd number of points, but's doable.
- Calculate the start `Point` either by using the preferred size or some other means (like using a `ComponentListener` and monitoring the `componentResized` method.  This becomes tricky as your component may be resized a number of times when it is first created and released to the screen and you will want to ignore future events once you have your first point)